# Multithreading and sleeping for responsive UI in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I was reading this on Multithreading: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/j5e_multithreading.html

It recommends *(not requires)* that you add a `Thread.sleep(10)` in the CPU intensive task for single core CPUs, and that effectively by doing this, you are giving the CPU extra time to update all of the other threads it has (and most importantly, the UI of the program, which I'm trying to improve).

This doesn't make any sense to me.  While my program is unresponsive, the rest of my computer is running just fine, and I believe that it is Windows that gives allotted CPU time to each program.

Regardless, is this good advice?  If it is, am I saying "Here's a bonus 10 milliseconds for the other threads", or would `Thread.sleep(0)` work just fine?

Comment: Sounds like an advice born from the time when some Java implementations had green threads (simulated threads) instead of real threads

Comment: @Mark wouldn't Thread.yield() be more apropriate then?

Comment: @haraldK Probably, to be honest I have never before seen advice to use `sleep` for responsiveness, and to be honest I have never actually needed to use `yield` either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a good advice for an article dated back to 2004 (as it references JDK5 new features) and first dual core processors were there in 2006. When you had single core and for a long running process thread yielding  would make your system more responsive.

I think the same technique could be applied today if your app loads all available cores. For the example in an article I think this long-running action could be just dropped to a thread pool with no yielding.

**UPDATE**

Thread yielding is very much environment-dependent: [yield(), sleep(0), wait(0,1) and parkNanos(1)](http://vanillajava.blogspot.ru/2012/04/yield-sleep0-wait01-and-parknanos1.html)

> If you want to wait for a short period of time, you can't assume that all these methods do the same thing, nor will be the same between platforms.

Comment: `yield()` is not trustful at all.

Comment: This is the first I've heard of `yield()` not working as intended, is this a fact or mere suspicion?

Comment: @WayneUroda According to the API, `yield()`is "A hint to the scheduler that the current thread is willing to yield its current use of a processor. The scheduler is free to ignore this hint."  So, it doesn't guarantee other threads' execution, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @AndreyChaschev "I think the same technique could be applied today if your app loads all available cores."  On my computer, I am using about 25% CPU...assuming this product isn't going commercial, am I safe to assume that it won't load all available cores?

Comment: @MrTi Sure. It's very hard to think of a Desktop user app that would intentionally load 4 cores. If it is some research on a single user machine (not on a cluster), I would recommend loading 3 cores maximum just to avoid troubles.

Comment: @AndreyChaschev really how are you going to tell JVM to utilize only 3 core of 4? unless you get some hand of native guys.

Comment: @user2511414 by submitting tasks to a fixed thread pool with 3 threads maximum (`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3)`).

Comment: @AndreyChaschev disagree! at the first this is possible all threads are run by one core! second you cannot limit application to utilize only 3 threads! this is awful. consider we have 33 thread and 4 cores, how are you going to tell JVM to utilize/don't-utilize n cores?! Executor is a thread pool, not a low-level hw thread manager.

Comment: True that it's bad to dump all your tasks to this thread pool. It might be a good idea to segregate tasks by a job type, e.g. submit CPU-intensive tasks to 3-threads pool, instant UI tasks to an UI thread, some other tasks - i.e. IO tasks which might be blocked to a third thread pool with some reasonable limitation for threads.

Comment: @AndreyChaschev check [this example](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/07/java-thread-example.html#lc), this is talking about running to much threads at a time (around 240 with 1080p). I have a 4 core (8 thread) CPU here, but this application just utilize 2 core  and two thread to run the threads, not whole the threads. I'm saying low-level thread management is not a java api thing. JVM decides, 3 thread doesn't mean run only 3 CPU threads.

Comment: Thanks, that's really interesting. Let's move to chat if you want to discuss this - I don't think you need 360 threads if you have 360 formulas, the optimal number of threads for 360 formulas is the number of available cores.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40897/discussion-between-andrey-chaschev-and-user2511414)

Answer (score 2):

This is an obviously old advice from times where a sleep on Windows would cause the main thread to be put on pause and background-threads to be processed. You can imagine that old threading concept as a queue and only the front thread gets processing time. As soon as that one is put on hold (on Windows even sleep(1) is enough), the current thread will be put to the end of the queue and other threads will be processed.

Modern OS however handle this entirely different and that advice is today a sign of bad implementation of multi-threading. Java gives you the option to set the priority of a thread and allows you to easily use background-threads for heavy processing. Today you would implement it like this:

First we need a ThreadFactory for low-priority Threads:

```
public class PriorityThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {

  protected final ThreadGroup allThreads;

  public PriorityThreadFactory(final String name, final int priority, final boolean daemon) {
    this.allThreads = new ThreadGroup(name);
    this.allThreads.setMaxPriority(priority);
    this.allThreads.setDaemon(daemon);
  }

  @Override
  public Thread newThread(final Runnable r) {
    return new Thread(this.allThreads, r);
  }
}
```

Then we create an ExecutorService and set the priority to `Thread.MIN_PRIORITY`:

```
final PriorityThreadFactory threadFactory = new PriorityThreadFactory("workers", Thread.MIN_PRIORITY, true);
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), threadFactory);
```

Finally we can submit any number of tasks and they will be processed in the background and will not block important threads like the UI-Thread.

```
executor.submit(new MyWorkerTask());
```

Comment: how are saying `sleep(1) is enough in win machines`!? can you prove it? it dependents on many things. sometimes it would be 50 ns, or even 10 ms.

Comment: Windows 95-ME had a time-slice system that would grant every thread a slice of 10ms or until it was done/paused. So if you did yield/sleep in any form, the earliest the thread was resumed was 10ms later.
This has been changed on modern Windows entirely.